# Cannot load variable because of not callable str obj

Tags: python-3.x

I am having this error no matter what I have tried. I attempted using edf(edf_size), and int(edf_size).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
enter code hereFile "C:/Users/Joshua/PycharmProjects/Plane Maker/main.py", line 229, in <module>
    file.write("The EDF Thrust Tube is "+ edf() + " inches.\n")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

It corresponds with these two sections of code:

```
edf_size = int(input("Enter the edf size, only the number portion in mm (like 64): "))
character = input("Do you want a plane with speed, power, or both? ")
while True:
    if (character == "speed"): break
    if (character == "power"): break
    if (character == "both"): break

file.write("The EDF size is "+ str(edf_size) + " mm.\n")
file.write("The EDF Thrust Tube is "+ edf() + " inches.\n")
```

and

```
#Set edf tube length
def edf():
    global edf_size
    thrust_tube = (edf_size * 25.4) * 4
    return str(thrust_tube)
```

.
.
.
Please help me I really just dont know why it won't work.

Comment: It looks like somewhere in your code you've done `edf = "some string"` which then overwrote your `edf` function.

Comment: Yeah and I fixed it thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to use the Global?

Can you try this?

```
file.write("The EDF Thrust Tube is "+ edf(edf_size) + " inches.\n")

#Set edf tube length 
def edf(elf_size):
    thrust_tube = (edf_size * 25.4) * 4
    return str(thrust_tube)
```

Also are you sure you are not redefining edf as a string somewhere in your code?

Comment: so it turns out that I was redefining it. I had an input variable named edf and that function named edf, so I changed the variable and it works now. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: @JoshuaParker glad I could help!